# How can I connect from SSMS to SQL Server in a Docker container? It worked before but then stopped

Tags: sql-server, docker

I’m trying to get SQL Server to work in a Docker container. I had it working the other day and could connect vial SSMS, but now I get the error message below. I’ve googled it many times and all I see is that the message usually has to do with TLS. I have 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 enabled on my laptop, but I have no idea how to check or setup TLS inside a Ubuntu Docker container running SQL Server. Have any of you seen this error before and perhaps know how to solve it? I'm currently running the image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest, but I've also tried 2022 and 2017 and see the same results. I'm running on a Windows 10 laptop but have also tried this on Windows Server 2022 and see the same results.
[image: SQL Error]

Comment: On the advanced tab, try trusting the server certificate or not encrypting the connection. The defaults changed to encrypt and not trust by default.

Comment: Thanks Randy. Just tried that - same result.

Comment: Other things to check.  Is TCP\IP enabled?  Does the log show the SPN being created?  Is the firewall open on both sides?  Try connecting by IP,port?  (I think there are many possible reasons for this error.)

Comment: If my server was working and stopped, I will normally suspect a firewall or a domain policy change as a possible cause.  A repair - binaries and permissions only - might fix it for a short while as a test of policy.  A port test can verify if required ports are open.

Comment: Are you publishing the Docker container's port 1433 on host port 1443? Because normally it would be listening on port 1433. If that's correct then are you watching the Docker container's log output while trying to connect from SSMS? It may be reporting useful error information.

Comment: @RandyinMarin  TCP/IP is definitely enabled on my laptop. I don't know how to tell if it is inside the container, but the message "A connection was successfully established..." makes me think it is. Not totally sure how to check whether there's a firewall issue, but I was just able to stop the container (port 1433) and create a sample website at that port and that works fine so I'm assuming it's not a firewall thing. The log has no mention of SPN. I've tried both 1433 and 1443. This screenshot happens to show 1443.

Comment: The sql server log will have a message near the start about the SPN being or not being created.  However, it might be hard to see if unable to use SSMS.  Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash will help.